# Getting Dummy Output in ubuntu 18.04, no sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

[image: sound settings screenshot]

**Hardware:**

- MB: m5a97 r2.0
- Graphics: GForce  GT 630 (nvidia-driver-390)
- Headphones: Kensington model: 33137

**Software:** Ubuntu 18.04 Fresh install/ fully updated

`ubuntu-drivers devices`:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:06:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000F00sv00001462sd00008A90bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF108 [GeForce GT 630]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:06:00.1 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000BEAsv00001462sd00008A90bc04sc03i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF108 High Definition Audio Controller
driver   : oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms - third-party free
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
06:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [1462:8a90]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`sudo lshw -c sound`

```
*-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: GF108 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:21 memory:fe080000-fe083fff
```

`sudo lsof /dev/snd/*`

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi  1372    gdm   18u   CHR 116,10      0t0  471 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 10150 walter   17u   CHR 116,10      0t0  471 /dev/snd/controlC0
```

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`dpkg -l | grep audio`

```
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1                amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  libaudio2:amd64                            1.9.4-6                                      amd64        Network Audio System - shared libraries
ii  libavc1394-0:amd64                         0.5.4-4build1                                amd64        control IEEE 1394 audio/video devices
ii  libavcodec-extra57:amd64                   7:3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        FFmpeg library with additional de/encoders for audio/video codecs
ii  libcdio-cdda2:amd64                        10.2+0.94+2-2build1                          amd64        library to read and control digital audio CDs
ii  libcdio-paranoia2:amd64                    10.2+0.94+2-2build1                          amd64        library to read digital audio CDs with error correction
ii  libcdparanoia0:amd64                       3.10.2+debian-13                             amd64        audio extraction tool for sampling CDs (library)
ii  libchromaprint1:amd64                      1.4.3-1                                      amd64        audio fingerprint library
ii  libmpg123-0:amd64                          1.25.10-1                                    amd64        MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder (shared library)
ii  libpcaudio0                                1.0-1                                        amd64        C API to different audio devices - shared library
ii  librubberband2:amd64                       1.8.1-7ubuntu2                               amd64        audio time-stretching and pitch-shifting library
ii  libsndfile1:amd64                          1.0.28-4                                     amd64        Library for reading/writing audio files
ii  libswresample2:amd64                       7:3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        FFmpeg library for audio resampling, rematrixing etc. - runtime files
ii  libtag1v5:amd64                            1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.2build2                      amd64        audio meta-data library
ii  libtag1v5-vanilla:amd64                    1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.2build2                      amd64        audio meta-data library - vanilla flavour
ii  libvisual-0.4-0:amd64                      0.4.0-11                                     amd64        audio visualization framework
ii  libwavpack1:amd64                          5.1.0-2ubuntu1.2                             amd64        audio codec (lossy and lossless) - library
ii  libwebrtc-audio-processing1:amd64          0.3-1                                        amd64        AudioProcessing module from the WebRTC project.
ii  pulseaudio                                 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1                            amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-equalizer                       1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1                            amd64        Equalizer sink module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1                            amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                           1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1                            amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
ii  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64      0.8.8-1ubuntu1                               amd64        Speech Dispatcher: Audio output plugins
ii  ubuntu-sounds                              0.13                                         all          Ubuntu's GNOME audio theme
```

`dkms status`

```
nvidia, 390.77, 4.18.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`sudo apt-get remove oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 630]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: I have had a similar problem recently.  Please execute `sudo lsof /dev/snd/*` and `aplay -l` and post the results of these commands into your question.

Comment: added output from commands

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep audio` and `dkms status`.

Comment: Added requested outputs.

Comment: The question is where `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms` is coming from?

Comment: I was responding to your other answer there,  but it looks like you deleted it.    My response to that is I dont know how it got installed.  This is a fresh install of 18.04 downloaded from the Ubuntu website.  The only "extra" driver I manually installed was the nvidia-driver-390  for my video card.    Anything else that got installed was done automatically buy the system.

Comment: @Pilot6 `ubuntu-drivers devices` indicated that `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms` was loaded as the driver for the audio part of the device.

Comment: It is weird that dkms doesn't show it. Try to remove it there.

Comment: based on this information https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS   I tried to uninstall it: Results in original question.  but its not found.  I also checked synaptic and its not listed as installed there either.

Comment: That's weird too. `dpkg -l` was for that. I am lost.

Comment: K - I got a suggestion.  It is not apparent yet, that you have installed the drivers for your NVidia device.  can you add the output of `sudo lshw -c video`?  I am not comfortable suggesting a particular nvidia driver, as I don't use one, and there are lots of them.

Comment: So before I saw your comment,  I tried something.  I purged all mention  of NVidia i could from my system.  Then I upgrade to the 4.20 kernel.  Now when I check  ubuntu-drivers devices:  that oem driver is still listed.  It...wont uninstall.

Comment: Just did a complete format and reinstall of 18.04.  Didn't install any updates or extras.   First thing I checked was the sound.  And its the same.  Im beginning to think its a hardware/bios issue.

Comment: @CharlesGreen  Added the output of the command.

Comment: Thanks Walter.  I would still suggest trying one of the nvidia video drivers, as the sound and graphics seem to be combined in some manner in this card.

Comment: I have the nvidia 390 driver installed for the graphics.  After a full reinstall The audio device is not even listed anymore.    I ended up just using an old bluetooth dongle I have for a pair of headsets.  There's the issue with the delay in audio,   but for now I have something.  Im not going to mark this as resolved.  Hopefully Ubuntu can fix it.  I've started a bug on it.

Comment: Hey!  I found something!  [https://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/gpu-hdmi-audio-document/index.html#issues_in_alsa](https://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/gpu-hdmi-audio-document/index.html#_trouble_shooting) ===  try `sudo modprobe snd_hda_codec_hdmi` == you **do** need the nvidia driver running, and they have a short trouble shooting section!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem....   I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a Dell laptop, and upgraded to linux Kernal 5.0 a couple days ago, then this morning when I logged in Ubuntu wanted to do a software update.   after that no sound..   After  a reboot, it is "Dummy Output".   If I run "pactl load-module module-detect", Settings will then show "Built-in Analog Audio" but when I do the SPeaker Test I get nothing..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes this, but I've been having the same issue for months with Linux Mint 19.1.

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

This fixes it for me, but not permanently. I have this command saved in a document in my home folder for whenever I need it.

If someone else could chime in on why this is happening/status of it being fixed that would be much appreciated. Problems like this are what keep Windows users from switching to Linux.

Comment: Based on other questions Ive found on this,  I've tried this command and the pulseaudio -k command.  Neither work for me.